# Manga/webcomic where the main character can see something's luck (the thing he focuses on becomes green)

Tags: story-identification, manga

I distinctly remember that the mc of what I was reading could sorta see luck, just by focusing on things and they turn green.

It starts out with the mc's past of trying to be a gambler, and then his power starts to fade and he starts to run out of money. He was going to jump into a lake or waterway or something, then some lady comes along and wants him to join some program with other people. He says yes, as long as he gets to be a fancy contract thingy, and when he gets there, people get certain things depending on some system. Most get copper rank, a select few get the silver rank, and I know the mc gets golden rank.

He also finds out he has some unique skill that basically color codes things depending on what they are, like red for danger or black for death. I really enjoyed the first parts, but I couldn't remember what this one was called. The art was a solid 7.6/10 and the plot was fun. Also I remember the people receive their ranking along with gifts inside this school-is building and a monster comes out of the gym floor and bites some girl in half, and her little brother tries to save her but fails.

Events happen, like one where zombies appear, or you have to gather tokens, and some girl with a hoody has a broken arm. There's this annoying old bitch who causes issues, as well as her douchebag husband fella. I know that the monster and events were some kind of tutorial, and then when the mc gets to the main area (Paradise?), he can take quests from some quest board, and he picks a hard one which involves fighting skeletons, and he fails pretty bad and then he trains and takes the mission again.

Thats the most I can remember, so can someone plz help me?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

I found the name from a similar question. I was looking for a manhwa called "Second Coming of Gluttony". Thanks to Valorum for commenting on my question as well as solving both mine and someone else's question.

Comment: You will be able to accept your self-answer by clicking on the check-mark as per the [tour] although, as a self answer, you have to wait 48 hours from the time of asking, so about 10 PM EST tomorrow. :)